# How to dynamically connect to wifi hotspots when I find them?

Tags: wifi

I'm doing a robotics project in which I have multiple raspberry pi powered robots. When they meet eachother one of them can decide to set up a wifi hotspot and the other ones should connect to it.

When a robot sets up a hotspot, the SSID will contain the number of the robot: `robot_1`, `robot_2`, etc.

Every robot should scan for wifi networks every 10 seconds (`nmcli dev wifi`) and when it detects a network called `robot_x` it should connect to it. To make it easier for now, all the networks will have the same password.

I know how to connect to a network by defining it in the `wpa_supplicant.conf`, but I don't want to define all the networks in all the robots. I could of course programatically edit the `wpa_supplicant.conf` when I detect a network, but I've got a feeling there's a better way to do this.

Does anybody know how I can make this work more dynamic so that when I know which network is available (for example `robot_78`) I can then connect to it using some kind of command?

All tips are welcome!

Comment: It's really interesting!  

**Example:** By default, all the robots have an enabled hotspot `robot_x` and also always are trying to connect to hotspot `robot_x`.

If `robot_1` get close to `robot_2`, the `robot_1` realized that a `robot_x` is reachable in the wifi list and try to connect to `robot_2`. So, `robot_1` deduced that connected to a hotspot and try yo disable their hotspot.  

**Now:** `robot_1`=> hotspot disabled, connected to `robot_2`. `robot_2`=> hotspot enabled, stop finding `robot_x`. || It's gonna be the mechanisem, agreed?

Comment: You have an idea in your head and asked for a detail to realize the idea. But maybe there is a better idea to connect the robots? May I ask why do you want to use dynamically access points? What's your idea? I have an idea how to manage the access points but it's a bit complex and I also have an idea that may be simpler but I don't know if its possible for you. Please address me with @Ingo.